# Bash Append Suffix to Variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that would add a prefix to a variable, but I can't seem to get it added. I've tried using ++1 and a few others but I'm not sure how to do this. Here's the bash

```
HOSTNAME=TEST-HOST

for i in {1..5};
do COMMAND IS RUN HERE AND INCLUDES $HOSTNAME;
done
```

Comment: Your code only shows a simple use of a variable and that should work if $HOSTNAME is not in single quotes. Where do you apply a prefix?

Comment: I'd like to add an incrementing number to the end of the $HOSTNAME variable. i.e 01, 02, 03 etc;

Comment: Do you mean like e.g. `ping ${HOSTNAME}${i}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need TEST-HOST1 you can just use `$HOSTNAME$i` inside your loop.

If you need TEST-HOST01 you can use `$(printf "%s%02d" $HOSTNAME $i)`